# Reset the value as null jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojox.grid.datagrid

I want to reset the value of docId as null.

Can you please show me how to do this?

```
console.dir(dijit.byId("grid"));
rowIndex = e.rowIndex;
var item = this.getItem(rowIndex);
var docId = this.store.getValue(item, "ID");
```

Comment: Please rewrite this question in proper English, with proper punctuation. It is not understandable as it is written now. I REALLY tried to rewrite it for you but I do not get what you want. What is m?

Comment: here i want one condition depends on docid value,if docid is null,it will prefrom different task

Comment: i want to reset this value as null.....@humble.rumble

Answer (score 0):

Use [unsetAttribute](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/data/api/Write.html#unsetattribute), like this:

```
rowIndex = e.rowIndex;
var item = this.getItem(rowIndex);
this.store.unsetAttribute(item, "ID");
```

and don't forget to refresh the grid:

```
this.update();
```